# set default route interface in iproute2

Tags: route, iproute2

I have two machines. One runs arch linux and another runs fedora. arch uses iproute2. so i need a conversion for iproute2 from route. this command will set the default interface to ppp0.

I have searched for [documentation](http://www.policyrouting.org/iproute2.doc.html) but I have still no clue.

How shall do this in iproute2

```
route add default ppp0
```

Answer (score 5):

```
ip route add default via 192.0.2.254
```

You can't specify a device for a route, it has to be an address.  Generally you shouldn't have to do this at all; `pppd` should take care of adding a default route if it is configured appropriately.

Comment: I have two NICs, eth0 and ppp0, so i need to bond a default interface.

Comment: No you don't.  Routing doesn't work like that.

Comment: It's entirely valid to specify a device as a default route. It's only valid when that interface is a point-to-point though.

Comment: so basically, each line output of `ip route` is syntactically-valid input to `ip route add` (?)

Answer (score 2):

I found it, its

```
ip route add default dev ppp0
```